# Possessive pronoun, how to use them as "Stellvertreter" vs. "Begleiter"?

Tags: grammar, pronoun

I am learning about *Possessivpronomen* few days now, but there is one thing confusing me.

When I am looking at the table, I see *Begleiter* possessive pronouns and *Stellvertreter* possessiv pronouns.

I understand that I need to use a *Begleiterpossessivpronomen* in front of a noun, but I dont understand, when I need to use *Stellvertreterpossessivpronomen*?

Can you please explain me when I use a *Stellvertreter*?

Answer (score 7):

I just realized the answer.

> Die (meisten) Pronomen dienen als Platzhalter oder Stellvertreter für ein Nomen. <sup>[Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Pronomen/index.html)</sup>

I use a *Begleiterpossesivpronomen* with the noun, and a *Stellvertreterpossesivpronomen* without a noun!

> Dies ist mein Auto - Dieses Auto ist meines

So simple!